# Can I use external location as a separate server for git-lfs?

Tags: github, azure-devops, git-lfs

I have a repository on GitHub.com. I need to add a large file to it (>1GB). git-lfs seems to be the solution but GitHub probably offers only upto 2GB for free. Can I use any other location as a separate large file server while the actual codes stay in GitHub?

I tried configuring lfs Endpoint to the Azure devops repo and the git origin to GitHub.com. It does not seem to be working that way.

Comment: **Why** do you need to add a 1 GB file? Is it versioned or static? Is it required for building your application? I would strongly recommend treating LFS as a last resort and storing the file in something like Azure DevOps Universal Packages or the GitHub equivalent.

Comment: The file is required for running my application. The best I can do is users to request me to send them the file separately but I want that when they clone the GitHub repo for running the application, it is downloaded with it.

Comment: The why-question is a different topic, I guess we shouldn't discuss why to use git lfs. But I'm also interested in this topic. Maybe someone has some insight on that?